# XML schema validation works when restriction pattern is integer not for string

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

My XML Schema works when pattern is integer but not for strings.

my XML for string gives me

***a is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-z]' for type 'oldPhone'***

XML:

```
<phone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./phone.xsd">

  <oldPhone>
    a
  </oldPhone>
</phone>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="oldPhone">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-z]"/>
       </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="phone">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "oldPhone" type = "oldPhone"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

It works simply when I substitute `xs:string` with `xs:integer`, change from `[a-z]` to `[0-9]` and change the input in XML to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern match fails because of the whitespace around the value.

The reason it works for xs:integer is that xs:integer has an implicit whiteSpace facet of "collapse", which causes leading and trailing whitespace to be stripped before the pattern match is applied. You can achieve the same effect with strings either by adding an explicit whiteSpace facet, or by using xs:token as your base type instead of xs:string.

Alternatively change the pattern to permit the leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: I see, so to fix it I would either change the xs:token or add an explicit whiteSpace facet. Could you explain a bit more about what you mean by "adding an explicit whiteSpace facet"? Also a bit more about "whiteSpace facet of "collapse""?

Comment: Or if there is a website or book talks about this? Thanks!

Comment: I understand it now.Thanks!

Comment: I am constantly amazed how far people manage to get using some of these technologies before it occurs to them to ask whether there is a book or website that would help.